# InstallShield moved project no upgrade prompt

Tags: notifications, upgrade, installshield, prompt

I have an InstallShiled project that has been moved from another system. I can build the install package, do upgrades and everything goes well, BUT if I try to do a minor upgrade to a previously deployed application that has been installed from an installation package built on the previous machine, it does not prompt the user that the app will be upgraded. It is like it does not recognize as the same Product, yet everything works as it should, like a normal upgrade.

The Product and Upgrade Codes have not been changed. Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the Direct Editor:

Go to upgrade table and add new record having following value in min and max versions according to upgrade or downgrade prevention scenario :

> *****ALL_VERSIONS*****

This expression evaluates to current product version at runtime.

From there you can also set a property which can be then used in a custom action to run whatever code you want be it a dll, vbscript or almost anything.